# copyWithZone-unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c

I am using the following code to instantiate the view SenderPlayerViewController and pass the object "session" :

```
- (void)session:(GKSession *)session peer:(NSString *)peerID didChangeState: GKPeerConnectionState)state {
switch (state) {
    case GKPeerStateConnected:
        NSLog(@"Connected Central");
        if ([settings.playerType isEqualToString:@"SENDER"]){                 
            SenderPlayerViewController *myViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SenderPlayerViewController"];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
            myViewController.currentSession=session;

        }

        break;            
    case GKPeerStateDisconnected:
        NSLog(@"Disconnected Central");
        self.currentSession = nil;
        break;
}   
}
```

The header file of view SenderPlayerViewController is :

```
@interface CentralViewController : UIViewController {
Settings *settings;}
@property (nonatomic, copy) GKSession *currentSession;

@end
```

When the code is executed i get the following error :

```
[GKSession copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9661200
```

need more help here....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The property :

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) GKSession *currentSession;
```

is wrong. GKSession is not a copyable object. So you should just grab a reference to it by retaining:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) GKSession *currentSession;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your custome Class GKSession must be a subclass of NSObject,and You'd better implement the methood that declared in protocol NSCopy